# Prove if $f(z)=0$ when $z$ is on $C$, then $f'(z_0)=0$ where $z_0$ is on $C$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I know it maybe simple to you, but I stuck with this question for a long time. The question is came from a Schaum's book:

Let $f(z)$ be analytic in a region $R$ and let $C$ be a curve on $R$. If $f(z)=0$ when $z$ is on $C$, then $f(z_0)=f'(z_0)=f''(z_0)=f'''(z_0)=...=0$ where $z_0$ is on $C$.

Comment: look at the Taylor's expansion at $z_0$ of $f(z)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint! Since $f$ is analytic on $C$, it admits a Taylors series expansion at $z_0$ i.e

$0=f(z)=f(z_0)+(z-z_0)f'(z_0)+(z-z_0)^2 \frac {f''(z_0)} {2!}+\dots$

Comment: Let $z_1$ is also on $C$, then $0=f(z_1)=(z_1-z_0)f'(z_0)+(z_1+z_0)^2 \frac{f''(z_0)}{2!}+...$, but why it means that $f'(z_0)=0$ maybe after so many terms they can cancel out.

Comment: Taylor's expansion is unique, you can try to compare coefficients

Comment: but z is not all equal to zero in $R$, only on the curve $C$